# Determining the maximal ideals in $\mathbb{Z_2[x]}/(x^3 + x + 1)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Let $R = \mathbb{Z_2[x]}/(x^3 + x + 1)$

The elements of $R$ will be all polynomials in $\mathbb{Z_2[x]}$ with degree less than $x^3 + 2x + 1$.

So the elements of $R$ are -

$\overline{0}, \overline{1}, \overline{x}, \overline{x+1}, \overline{x^2}, \overline{x^2 + 1}, \overline{x^2 + x}, \overline{x^2 + x + 1}$

Then the maximal ideals are $(\overline{x}), (\overline{x+1}), (\overline{x^2 + x + 1})$ as any ideals generated by the elements of $R$ will be contained in one of these ideals.

Have I got all that correct?

Comment: The title of the question says you are modding out by $x^3+2x+1$ but the question text says $x^3+x+1$. This makes a difference because $x^3+2x+1=x^3+1=(x+1)(x^2+x+1)$ is not irreducible mod $2$, but $x^3+x+1$ is irreducible. As Luis pointed out, if you really mean $x^3+x+1$, then your quotient is a field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your R is a field ( You modded out by an irreducible polynomial and hence maximal). What maximal ideals do you want to find? What are the ideals in a field?

Comment: I want to find all maximal ideals. I don't understand what the implication of modding by an irreducible polynomial is? What difference does it make whether I mod by an irreducible or a reducible polynomial?

Comment: @sonicboom: It might help you to notice that $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ is a PID. Do you know any theorem about PIDs, irreducible elements and ideals?

Comment: @nik No, I've heard a tutor mention that there was some significance to having an irreducible element as an ideal in a quotient but he didn't make it clear. Would you mind telling me what is the relationship between these concepts?

Comment: @nik I think you meant to say $\mathbb{Z}_2[x]$ is a PID. $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ is not a PID. (2,x) is not a principal ideal.

Comment: @sonicboom Since you are working in a principal ideal domain, an element is irreducible iff it is prime. Further prime ideals are maximal ideals in a PID. Quotioning by a maximal ideal gives you a field. By the way, it is not a bad idea to check directly that it is a field.

Comment: @Luis: Yes sorry I meant $\mathbb{Z}_2[x]$.